# A sheet removal causes an unreadable file error in OpenXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I try to remove a sheet from an Excel file and I have tried a lots of source from Internet but I always get the same result: unreadable content.

The link of the last one: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2010/02/05/how-to-delete-a-worksheet-from-excel-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0/

I also tried this:

```
 Sheet sheet = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => s.Name.Equals(sheetName));
 sheet.Remove();
 workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
```

Plus this:

```
sheet.RemoveAllChildren()
```

But the file is always corrupt.

Please!

**UPDATE**

```
 using (MemoryStream xlsxStream = new MemoryStream())
 {
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(templatePath))
       fileStream.CopyTo(xlsxStream);
    ...
    using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(xlsxStream, true, new OpenSettings { AutoSave = true }))
    {
       Sheet sheet = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().First(s => s.Name.Equals(sheetName));
       sheet.Remove();
       workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
       ...
```

Comment: Excel workbooks must contain at least one sheet, so you are essentially forcing the creation of a corrupt file.

Comment: Yes but there are multiple sheets (five) in Excel file and I want to leave one sheet in it at least.

Comment: The code you posted deletes everything. Please add the relevant code parts to the question.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand well. First I select the sheet by name and then I remove it from the sheet collection.

Comment: Without any more context I assume, that `workbook` is a newly created, valid instance that contains a single sheet. If you remove the sheet the WB becomes invalid. You need to add some contextual code for us to analyze the problem.

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry. :) I load in an Excel template then I fill its one sheet then I remove the others and save it as a new Excel file. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A potential solution to your answer may be an empty (and not needed) `CalculationChainPart`. For more details see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71599097/588894)